# Trying to fix a string function that takes a string and change it by replacing some words

Tags: c++

I am trying to fix a function that takes a string a checks whether it can find the numbers 4 and 5 and change them to N

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

string Newstring(string& Text);

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        string head = "";
        cout << "Input a string: ";
        getline(cin, head);
        cout << '\n';
        cout << "The new string is: ";
        cout << Newstring(head);
        cout << '\n';
        cout << "This is the end";
        cin.ignore();
        system("cls");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


string Newstring(string& Text)
{
    string NewText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i == '4' || i == '5')
        {
            i = 'N';
            NewText += Text[i];
        }
    }
    return NewText;
}
```

Input a string: 45fj ji

The new string is:
This is the end 
This is the output and it does not show the new string

Comment: `i = 'N'; NewText += Text[i];` What do you think this does?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that works and doesn't crash. That should probably through an "out of range" exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (i == '4' || i == '5')
{
    i = 'N';
    NewText += Text[i];
}
```

to this:

```
if (Text[i] == '4' || Text[i] == '5') {
    NewText += 'N';
} else {
    NewText += Text[i];
}
```

ERROR 1
you are checking if iteration through loop is equal to 4 or 5 with:

```
if (i == '4' || i == '5')
```

ERROR 2
You are assigning letter `N` to integer variable:

```
i = 'N';
```

But here is my ultimate solution for this problem:

```
std::string Newstring(const std::string& Text)                                                           
{
    std::string NewText (Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.length(); i++)
        if (NewText[i] == '4' || NewText[i] == '5')
            NewText[i] = 'N';

    return NewText;
}
```

Comment: 'NewText[i] = 'N';' this will crash as `NewText` is zero sized.  `NewText += 'N';` will do the job.

Comment: :) @Atul you are partially correct, it wont crash, but it will overflow. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're checking and updating the index i instead of the Text[i].

Check for 
`Text[i]=='4' && Text[i]=='5'` and also update 
`Text[i]='N'`

Answer (score 1):

You function need to be something like this:

```
string Newstring(string& Text)
{
    string NewText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.length(); i++)
    {
        if ((Text[i] == '4') || (Text[i] == '5'))
        {
            NewText += 'N' ;
        }
        else
        {
            NewText += Text[i];
        }
    }
    return NewText;
}
```

Comment: and also you do not need `()` around `Text[i] == 4` since `==` has presidency over `||`.

Comment: @0x476f72616e presidency correct. but it's good coding practice to still use parenthesis as it makes it more readable.

Comment: The parenthesis are actually unnecessary, but improves readability, I guess.